# Proof by induction that $\alpha^n + \beta^n \in \mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Let $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb C$ such $\alpha + \beta \in \mathbb Z$ and $\alpha \beta = j \in \mathbb Z$. Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb N,\alpha^n + \beta^n \in \mathbb Z$

Is this proof correct?

Basis: $n = 1$, then  $\alpha + \beta \in \mathbb Z$ by hypothesis.

Induction step:

Using complete induction, if $\alpha^i + \beta^i = k_i$ such $k_i \in \mathbb Z$ for all $i \leq n$, then I want to see that: $\alpha^{n+1} + \beta^{n+1} \in \mathbb Z$

then,

$$\alpha^{n+1} + \beta^{n+1} = \alpha\alpha^{n} + \beta\beta^{n} =$$
using: $\alpha^n + \beta^n = k_n$

$$ = \alpha(k_n - \beta^{n}) + \beta (k_n - \alpha^{n}) = $$

using: $\alpha \beta = j \in \mathbb Z$

$$= k_n(\alpha + \beta) - j(\alpha^{n-1} + \beta^{n-1}) =  $$

using induction again:

$$ = k_n k_1 - j k_{n-1}  $$

given that evry number is in $\mathbb Z$, then its proven.

Is this reasoning correct? it's correctly expressed?

Comment: Your proof is perfect, well done.

Comment: It might be better for clarity to use $\alpha^{n+1}+\beta^{n+1}=(\alpha^n +\beta^n)(\alpha+\beta)-\alpha\beta(\alpha^{n-1}+\beta^{n-1})$. This part probably should not mention induction.

Comment: The proof is *almost* correct. There is a small detail missing: Since your argument requires that both $\alpha^n+\beta^n$ and $\alpha^{n-1}+\beta^{n-1}$ are integers, the base case of your assumption should establish not just that $\alpha+\beta$ is an integer, but also that $\alpha^2+\beta^2\in\mathbb Z$, or $\alpha^0+\beta^0\in\mathbb Z$, if you prefer. Either one is easy, though of course that $\alpha^0+\beta^0\in\mathbb Z$ is trivial. Anyway, this must be mentioned explicitly.

Comment: Also, introducing new symbols, like $k_i$ can be useful, but also can make the reading harder. So $k_nk_1-jk_{n-1}$ looks different from what the title says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$